# Technical Description of Moving a Set of Points in $\mathbb{R}^2$ into $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: geometry, functions, differential-geometry, metric-spaces, euclidean-geometry

Given a set of points $A$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$, we can map the points into $\mathbb{R}^3$ in such a way that distances between points are preserved; intuitively, this mapping places the points in $\mathbb{R}^2$ in some plane in $\mathbb{R}^3$ while 'preserving' the shape made by the points.

What is a formal name for this mapping?  Would this the inverse mapping also have this formal name?

Is this an isometry?  Does the fact that the functions maps between two different metric spaces still allow it to be an isometry?

Comment: Wouldn't the map $A\ni (x,y) \mapsto (x,y,0)$ do what you want?

Comment: Maybe an embedding is what you're looking for? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embedding

Comment: Is the question about the terminology only? Then I would just say "a distance-preserving map". Avoid the term "isometry" that already has a very precise definite meaning, almost universally accepted.

Comment: That is correct; the question is about the general name given to maps that preserve distance (even if the map is between different metric spaces).

Comment: @GiorgosGiapitzakis Yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called an "isometric embedding." You could also call it an [isometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isometry) but that term is a little ambiguous since it is often used to mean an isometric bijection.

Comment: What are some isometric embeddings that are not bijective?

Comment: @FabrizzioMuzz: you gave an example yourself! A suitable embedding of $\mathbb{R}^2$ into $\mathbb{R}^3$ (say, $(x, y) \mapsto (x, y, 0)$) has this property.